# Java String Masking using concatenation

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

What is wrong with masking a data like this using concatenation?

```
linkedNumber = linkedNumber.substring(0,3)+"XXXXXXXX"+ linkedNumber.substring(linkedNumber.length-4);
```

What performance problems would this cause? How can `StringBuilder` help here ?

Comment: Can you include some sample strings which you are trying to mask?  It is kind of hard to answer what you wrote above.

Comment: Did you know `String` concatenation is *implemented* with a `StringBuilder`? Why do you think this causes performance problems?

Comment: *FYI:* The code might work better, i.e. compile, if you add the missing `()` to the `length` method call.

Answer (score -1):

When we do String manipulation like concat, substring etc, it creates new string object for result of the manipulation function and make eligible older string for garbage collection. So, these are heavy operations and generates new objects and  lot of garbage in heap memory.

**StringBuffer** and **StringBuilder** are mutable objects in java and provide append(), insert(), delete() and substring() methods for String manipulation.

**StringBuffer** provides Thread safety but on a performance cost as its methods are synchronized,but **StringBuilder** is not thread safety. So, if you don't care about thread safety (**single threaded environment**), use **StringBuilder** for b**etter perfomance.**

Comment: Someone down-voted my answer. May I know what is the wrong with above answer?

Answer (score -1):

> What is wrong with masking a data like this using concatenation?

Nothing, as long as you ensure `linkedNumber` is at least 4 characters long, though the code only makes sense if it is more than 7 characters long.

> What performance problems would this cause?

None.

> How can `StringBuilder` help here ?

The following code might be a microscopically faster, by not creating intermediate `String` objects for the 2 substrings, though I doubt you'd notice it, since they are so small (3 and 4 characters, respectively).

```
linkedNumber = new StringBuilder()
        .append(linkedNumber, 0, 3)
        .append("XXXXXXXX")
        .append(linkedNumber, linkedNumber.length() - 4, linkedNumber.length())
        .toString();
```